# Concurrent Clean linker error (weird)

Tags: functional-programming, linker-errors, clean-language

Downloaded latest version of "Concurrent Clean" (2.4) for Windows.  It installs, the IDE runs.  I can compile and run a ridiculously simple program:

```
module blah
Start = 1
```

The problem is, if I make any change at all (for instance Start = 2, or Start = [1,2,3] or Start = "hi") then the linker says that it could not create the executable.  If I delete the existing executable, it can create the executable.  Sometimes, if I spawn out of the IDE and come back in, it can create it.

I suspected Windows Defender so I shut it off.  Then I suspected UAC so I did as much as I could to shut it off (I don't think you can truly shut it off, but you can adjust the "level" on some control panel GUI).

As a final resort I downloaded version 2.2, and got the same error.

At any rate, if anyone has any ideas or suggestions, I'm listening.

Answer (score 0):

If the program is still running in the background, the Clean IDE won't replace the executable and thus can't run the linker. Make sure your application isn't running when you try to compile in the CleanIDE.